# Received an unsupported type from Postgres. (14) (SQLGetData)

Tags: postgresql, migration, mysql-workbench, odbc, schema-migration

I have database in PostgreSQL. It is simplest possible database with schema presented here:

> http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-table/

I want to migrate it to MySQL. I trying to follow after tutorial:

> https://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-mysql-using-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/

I installed ODBC, but during testing connection I have error:

```
Could not connect to Source DBMS.
[07006] Received an unsupported type from Postgres. (14) (SQLGetData)

ODBC connection string: DRIVER=PostgreSQL ANSI;SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=5432;DATABASE=test;UID=daniel;UseDeclareFetch=1;
```

[image]

My system: Ubuntu 18.

## Update 1

I simplified considered schema to single table

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL
);
```

I found similar topic on stackoverflow:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199390/error-when-trying-to-migrate-postgresql-db-to-mysql-with-workbench

changed driver value to `psqlODBC` and problem still exists. I can connect to database from Datagrip without problems.

Comment: Based on some posts around the internet, which exact driver version are you using?  Can you try the Unicode (64 bit) variant?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this? - I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 and the latest Workbench